# My Picture Box is following the Cursor, but the Cursor isn't Centered inside it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

So the cursor is offset a few pixels to the top left of the image

Here's the code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

 private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     pictureBox1.Left = MousePosition.X - (pictureBox1.Width/2);
     pictureBox1.Top = MousePosition.Y - (pictureBox1.Height/2);
 }
```

Comment: Can you show a picture which demonstrates the problem? Afair cursor point is upper left corner, not middle. You may have to take this into account (add half of [cursor size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.size) too).

Comment: `MousePosition` give you the position of the mouse in **screen** coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.Location` properties instead of `MousePosition`:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Left = e.Location.X - (pictureBox1.Width / 2);
    pictureBox1.Top = e.Location.Y - (pictureBox1.Height / 2);
}
```

`MousePosition` returns the position of the mouse in **screen** coordinates, while `e.Location` returns the position of the mouse relative to client bounds.

**EDIT**

For smoother movement try:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.MouseMove += pictureBox1_MouseMove;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    OnMouseMove(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);

    var location = PointToClient(MousePosition); // e.Location;

    pictureBox1.Left = location.X - (pictureBox1.Width / 2);
    pictureBox1.Top = location.Y - (pictureBox1.Height / 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but is there a way to make it any less laggy. What I noticed is that MousePosition doesn't work, but the program works smoothly with it, but e.location works, but it kinda stutters as I move the mouse around.

Comment: @BioloItz try adding an event hanlder to `pictureBox1.MouseMove` event.